# Blocking the UI thread while waiting for network activity

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I am now maintaining a piece of software written in VB.net (.net 3.5) that communicates over the network with another software running elsewhere which I have no control over.  I am not very familiar with WinForms software or best practices, but here's what I understand about the program:

When certain actions are taken place by the user via the UI, the program sends a message to the host process and waits for a response to come back, handles the results of the response, and then allows the user to continue.  The UI must be locked while this conversation is taking place between the client and host.  This conversation may take up to two or three seconds depending on the amount of stress the host is under.

The writer of this software is blocking the UI thread with while loops while this communication is going on.  Obviously this is not a good approach as it can result in Windows reporting that the program has locked up and giving the option to exit.

My question is, what is the best practice for doing this.  The winforms program has several windows with hundreds of buttons and controls that all must be blocked during the communication.  Communication (and waiting) takes place as the result of hundreds of different possible user interactions with the program.  So, how can I block the whole program from accepting input, button presses, keyboard, etc. while the communication is going on?

Here's some stripped-down code of how it's currently working.  I'm not afraid of significantly rewriting the communications portion of this program.

```
Private clientSocket As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
Private serverStream As NetworkStream
Private readThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf readLoop)



Public Sub Connect()
    'This function called to start the connection when program starts
    Try
        clientSocket.Connect(_Address, _Port)
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

        readThread.IsBackground = True
        readThreadActive = True
        readThread.Start()


    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent communicationsErrorEvent("CONNECT: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub WriterLogOn(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String)
    'This Sub is called from a button press on a WinForm

    Dim xmlString As String = "blah" 'generate xmlstring to send to host including username and encrypted password

    communicationsState = state_WriterLogOn 'store the state from an enum
    'each communication type has its own enum

    write(xmlString)

    While communicationsState = state_WriterLogOn
        Thread.Sleep(1)
    End While
End Sub


Private Sub write(ByVal writeString As String)
    Try
        Dim outStream As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(writeString & Chr(0))
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
        serverStream.Flush()
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent communicationsErrorEvent("WRITE: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub readLoop()

    Try
        While (readThreadActive) 'always true unless changed in certain conditions

            Dim buffSize As Integer
            Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
            Dim numberOfBytesRead As Integer = 0
            Dim returnDataBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder

            Do
                numberOfBytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
                returnDataBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, numberOfBytesRead))
            Loop While serverStream.DataAvailable

            Dim returnData As String = returnDataBuilder.ToString()


            If (returnData.Length > 0) Then
                ParseMessage(returnData)
            End If

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)

        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent communicationsErrorEvent("READLOOP: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub ParseMessage(ByVal readdata As String)
    'This function parses the string received and does the appropriate things with it
    'And when appropriate it sets the state back to idle, allowing the UI thread to unblock
    communicationsState = state_Idle
End Sub
```

The read loop must be running at all times, because it also can receive unsolicited messages at any time that must be handled in the background without blocking the UI thread. (This is done from the ParseMessage() sub).

So, I know enough to know that this is a bad way to handle blocking the UI thread.  But after searching around, I haven't found a good solution for stopping all user input application-wide until some other communications received in a different thread releases it.

I have tried inserting code into the various UI methods that checks the state and stops buttons/keyboard/etc from doing anything, but there are so many different places I would need to insert this code, it feels like the wrong way to do it.  I have searched around, but only find questions about how to NOT block the UI thread.

How can this be handled without Threading.Sleep in the UI thread?  Is a modal form the way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The best practice is to *never* block the UI thread. If you need to prevent the user from taking actions, then *disable* the interactive portions of the UI until such time as it is safe for them to be used again. One options for disabling the UI is to start a modal "progress" dialog (which you mention at the end) though it is not the only option.

Comment: BackgroudWorker with ReportsProgress

Answer (score 0):

How about just disabling all controls on the form then displaying user feedback to state that a long running operation is in progress - perhaps a never ending progress bar? You can use the function below and just call it from where ever is required.

```
Public Sub DisableUI(frm as form)

For Each c as Control in frm.controls

'determine if control is already disabled and set a flag for later

If c.Enabled = False Then

c.Tag = "1"

Else

c.Enabled = False

End If

Next

End Sub

Public Sub EnabledUI(frm as form)

For Each c as Control in frm.controls

If c.Tag.toString = "1" Then

'Control should stay disabled

Else

c.Enabled = True

End If

Next

End Sub
```